# How can i passing two parameters to restful web service using http post? UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field , not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, http-post

My course pojo is ;

```
public class Course {
private int cid;
private String name;
private String code;
private int credit;

//Getters Setters
```

}

service :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addcourse" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response<Course> addCoursetoUser(@RequestBody Course course, @RequestBody User user) throws SQLException{

    if(new CourseDAO().addCoursetoUser(course, user))
        return new Response<>(...);
    else
        return new Response<>(...);

}
```

i am trying to send this json values to my web service, but i am getting this error :
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cid" (Class com.spring.model.Course), not marked as ignorable

```
{
"id" :3,
"name" : "Algorithms",
"code" : "COM367",
"credit" : 3,
"cid" : 28,
"username" : "selin",
"password" : "ssgg"
```

}

I have tried a lot of jsons but I always get this error.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: when i define a new class which has Course and User pojo like that :

public class CourseUser {
 private User user;
 private Course course;
        //Getters Setters
}
i changed my post method like that :

@RequestMapping(value="/addcourse" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody Response<Course> addCoursetoUser(@RequestBody CourseUser courseUser) throws SQLException{
  ..
 }

And i changed my json like 
{
    "course.id" : 3, 
    "course.name" : "Algorithms", ....
}

But still i am getting same error :
Unrecognized field "course.id" not marked as ignorable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You will need to wrap your two objects into a single object (maybe `CourseUser` or `CourseUserRequest`).

Also that error implies your `Course` class is missing the `cid` field in the Java model.

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all you need to write **getter and setter** method for all class members which you have declared in your pojo :

eg :

```
public class Course {
private int cid;

public int getCid()
{
      return this.cid ;
}

public void setCid(int cid)
{
    this.cid=cid;
}

}
```

**Second**
You can not have two request body param in your post method here either you need to define a parent pojo which has Course and User Pojo like this

```
public class MyClass{

private Course course ;

private User user ;

// getter setter for User and Course 

}
```

Of Course your json will be change if you use this  like :

```
{
"course.id" :3,
"course.name" : "Algorithms",
"course.code" : "COM367",
"course.credit" : 3,
"course.cid" : 28,
"user.username" : "selin",
"user.password" : "ssgg"
}
```